# unable to login oracle as sysdba

Tags: oracle

I just got 11gR2 running and was able to conn as sysdba. I shutdown and started up the database to mount a new pfile. Now, I cannot login as sysdba. My parameter for password file is:

```
 *.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
```

I am using sqlplus within the server. This is not a remote connection.

```
[oracle@oel56 ~]$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Feb 5 22:50:46 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> conn / as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Here's some more information:

```
[oracle@oel56 ~]$ grep -E "ine SS_DBA|ine SS_OPER" $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/config.c
#define SS_DBA_GRP "oracle"
#define SS_OPER_GRP "oracle"
[oracle@oel56 ~]$ id oracle
uid=500(oracle) gid=500(oracle) groups=500(oracle),54321(oinstall),54322(dba),54323(oper) context=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t
```

Comment: Do you have multiple oracle home?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of:
`grep -E "ine SS_DBA|ine SS_OPER" $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/config.c` and also 
`id oracle`

Thanks

Comment: Also, if the pw file has been created properly you should still be able to login with `sqlplus sys/pass as sysdba` - give that a go and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Phil. Thanks for your reply. I added the output in my question. I tried the sqlplus string as you shown, but it does not work. I am able to login doing "sqlplus  system/pass" but again I have no privileges as sysdba.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat - no, only 1 oracle home: [oracle@oel56 ~]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1

Answer (score 2):

The problem was I was using the variable TWO_TASK. Once I unset the variable, I nolonger had issues logging in a sysdba.

```
$ unset TWO_TASK
$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Feb 6 02:51:55 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> startup;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1707446272 bytes
Fixed Size          1336988 bytes
Variable Size         989858148 bytes
Database Buffers      704643072 bytes
Redo Buffers           11608064 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> exit
```

I found the answer [here](http://oracleappstechnology.blogspot.com/2010/08/connect-as-sysdba-ora-01031.html).